# How do I read the Perl 6 docs for something like $*REPO?

Tags: documentation, raku

I wanted to read the docs for `$*REPO`, which is an `Installation`. If I use *p6doc*, I get a big ugly error message (instead of a simple, user-friendly message):

```
$ p6doc Installation
Could not find Installation at line 0 in:
    /Users/brian/.perl6
    /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site
    /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/vendor
    /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6
    CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<140211490473264>
    CompUnit::Repository::NQP<140211475454056>
    CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<140211475454096>
  in sub locate-curli-module at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 218
  in sub locate-module at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 39
  in sub MAIN at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 92
  in block <unit> at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 225
```

Or, if I look for `CompUnit::DependencySpecification`, I get a different error message:

```
$ p6doc CompUnit::DependencySpecification
CompUnit::DependencySpecification is a builtin type, not an external module
  in sub locate-curli-module at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 218
  in sub locate-module at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 39
  in sub MAIN at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 92
  in block <unit> at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/resources/C3A18C4AD5209A1B226E53B2C22A5347E5AC4790 line 225
```

I don't really care that this is a built-in type. I still want to see its documentation.

Is this a Rakudo thing that's something over Perl 6? Is there some other way I'm supposed to read these docs? How do we expect normal programmers to see these docs?

Or, are these things even documented?

Comment: FWIW, $*REPO is not an `Installation`, it's `CompUnit::Repository::Installation`. I suspect you're using .WHAT to look up names, but that gives you the typeobject which when gisted only shows the short name. Use $*REPO.^name

Answer (score 2):

There simply isn't any documentation for this yet. If you want to be certain, clone the perl6/doc repo from github and run a `git grep <yourtypename>`. In this case, `CompuUnitRepo::Local::Installation` only shows up in type-graph.txt, which means could potentially be used to render a type graph image, but there's no actual docs for this type.